Is there a way to use different subsets of a dataframe for different variables in table1 in R
I am producing a summary tables for health variables. There are some conditional variables that only have observations for when a value of another variable has been selected: a factor variable with types of respiratory support if a patient has answered "yes" to if they had received it.
I am using table1 package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=table1
My problem is, a single table generated using "table1" will give the incorrect number of missing data for the type of respiratory support, as it includes patients who also answered "no" to "have they received respiratory support".
I want to know if it is possible to summarise the data for those who only answered "yes" in the table1 function.
For example, the dataset is like this:
data.frame(received_resp_support = c("no", "yes", "yes", "yes"), type_resp_support = factor(c(NA, "A", "B", NA)))

Where the first NA is because the individual did not receive support, and the second NA is genuine missing data. In table1, with this data frame, there are two observations for the missing data row when it should be one, based on what was described above.
library(table1)

table1(~received_resp_support+type_resp_support, data=a)



Maybe set the 1st na to "No support" ?

@zx8754 I think the percentages would not be accurate if you did that.

You might use type_resp_support as a stratification variable in your table1()-function. However, there are no missing values (NA) allowed. But you could replace NA with e.g. Missing in your data frame:
It would look like this:
a=data.frame(received_resp_support = c("no", "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
type_resp_support = factor(c("Missing", "A", "B", "Missing")))

table1(~received_resp_support | type_resp_support, data=a)


Or you can leave NA in your variable type_resp_support and use received_resp_support as stratification variable instead:
a=data.frame(received_resp_support = c("no", "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
type_resp_support = factor(c(NA, "A", "B", NA)))

table1(~ type_resp_support | received_resp_support , data=a)



Two options you can try, both involving summarising the two variables separately: A. Use table1, convert to flextables, and then combine the results, B. Use tbl_summary and tbl_stack from the gtsummary package.
A. table1
t1 <- table1(~received_resp_support, data=a)
t2 <- table1(~type_resp_support, 
        data=subset(a, subset=received_resp_support=="yes"))

flextable(bind_rows(t1flex(t1)$body$dataset, t1flex(t2)$body$dataset))


B. gtsummary
library(gtsummary)

tbl_stack(
  list(
    select(a, received_resp_support) |>
      tbl_summary(type = list(received_resp_support ~ "categorical")),
      filter(a, received_resp_support=="yes") |>
      select(type_resp_support) |>
  tbl_summary()
))


The differences between the two packages are that gtsummary tables can be stacked even if the headers differ (the first table is used as the header), and the default handling of missing values.
